# Applying for a visa in a country other than my own

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, b1-b2-visas, polish-citizens, warsaw

I am a Polish student in my second year of college studying and living in Frankfurt, Germany. I applied twice for a visa to visit the USA when I was in high school in Warsaw and was denied, partially because I went back after one month after getting denied the first time.

I want to go to see the USA and visit my close friend there for about three weeks.

Should I apply for a tourist visa while in Germany or would my chances be better if I spend the extra traveling money to go to Warsaw to apply?

Answer (score 1):

I would not personally consider your permanent residence as Frankfurt under the circumstances. Assuming that, as in your second year at college, you are between 17 and 79 then an interview is required (except is some cases for renewals). [The U.S. State Department's Visitor Visas page](http://travel.state.gov/content/visas/english/visit/visitor.html) mentions that and includes:

> You must schedule an appointment for your visa interview, generally, at the U.S. Embassy or Consulate in the country where you live. You may schedule your interview at any U.S. Embassy or Consulate, but be aware that it may be difficult to qualify for a visa outside of your place of permanent residence.

I'm guessing also that you might combine such a trip with other reasons for returning home anyway.

Comment: Ha! Well, I almost never browse SE on my mobile, but I know some people do.